# Can I terminate a running proc sql program in sas

Tags: sql, sas, proc, terminate

I use SAS EG 8.2.
And I know there is stop buttons on menu bar.
But sometimes when the requesting result of my proc sql program is little(??) bit large,
that stop buttons doesn't work.
It always goes where it hopes to go.
From time to time, it takes over 1 hour(. And now I'm waiting and asking for)...

So I hope to know how to terminate a running proc sql program at once.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of different possible issues here.

When you say `proc sql`, if you mean a job that is submitting code to a SQL database, you probably cannot force that job to quit.  Your database administrator would have to do that, on the SQL database end - SAS usually cannot do anything about it.

If it's a SAS job only in PROC SQL, then often the stop button will be fine.  But if not, and if it's not a local job, you may be able to use `PROC IOMOPERATE` to quit the job, depending on your permissions on the server.  *You* may not be able to, as it's generally restricted to administrators, but again your SAS Admin may be able to.  See [Chris Hemedinger's post on the subject](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2016/02/15/using-proc-iomoperate/); he also developed an EG add-in that will allow that to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is harder to control what SAS is doing when you use a front-end like Enterprise Guide to submit your SAS code instead of running SAS directly.

You could try disconnecting from the SAS Server and starting a new session.

Comment: Programmer-me wants to upvote this, as a reasonable solution.  Administrator-me wants to downvote, as the number of times our SAS server is brought down by people doing massive cartesian joins, killing session (but it doesn't really end), retrying, 3 or 4 times... sigh.